# Physical object is halfly inside another object when spawn. How to set point of spawn right?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I have a problem with calculating position for the GameObject for spawn (instantiate). There are: 1) cube. 2) room with floor and walls. 3) user that's clicking mouse. Cube has rigidbody and collider so when I spawn it at the point of user's click the cube is halfly inside the floor or a wall and physics pushes it away.

Point of click == Cube's center. So it spawn halfly inside another object.

The question is how to calculate position for spawn in a right way?

Example Image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `Collider.bounds` like this:

```
Collider col = cube.GetComponent<Collider>();
cube.position = mouseClickPos - col.bounds.extents;
```

Haven't tested the code, but hope you got the idea. You can find more about `Bounds` here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html

Answer (score 0):

The position of the cube takes from the center, To fix this You can change the Pivot point of the cube. Create empty gameobject take empty game object to the edge of the cube and put the cube inside it.

Comment: Yes i tried it, but the question is about what if there are 2 surfaces(floor and wall for ex) or more. Like in the picture. This trick works only with one.